# how to list specific resources(ex vm,cpu,memory) metrics with agent.googleapis.com/agent/ through postman

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, postman, google-api-client

I want to get the agent metrics in google cloud for resources such as cpu,vm, memory etc(they have already installed agents in the vms).  When I use metric.type=compute.googleapis.com/instance/usage_time, i am able to get the metrics through postman through the below restapi call with compute.googleapis.com/

```
 https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/<projectname>/timeSeries?key=XSDXCXCDDDDCDE#$# 
    &interval.endTime=2020-06-14T19:58:17.140600Z&interval.startTime=2020-05-14T18:58:17.140600Z&filter=metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time" AND
        metric.labels.instance_name = "i-xyz"&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_SUM&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=3600s&pageSize=20
```

But when I want to get the agent metrics using agent.googleapis.com/agent it is not working I

https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/?filter=metric.type="agent.googleapis.com/agent/usage_time"

I am getting the below 404 error for any agent metrics:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    html,
    code {
        font: 15px/22px arial, sans-serif
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to get the agent metrics through postman?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you’re using:
`filter=metric.type="agent.googleapis.com/agent/usage_time"` when in fact it should be `"agent.googleapis.com/cpu/usage_time"`. Make sure that you’re using the correct [prefix](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-cpu) to monitor CPU usage. I think that’s why you’re getting 404.